# Connection wth BigQuery on Google Cloud Platform using Spark with Scala

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

I am not able to connect to Big Query table from Spark on GCP.

https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bigquery-connector

I already tried steps present in above by providing project Id dataset name and table name link still no success .When I am trying to print the data using below code I am getting below error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/bigquery/BigQueryConfiguration
        at Main.main(Main.scala:27)
        at Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.orgapachesparkdeploySparkSubmitrunMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitanon2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryConfiguration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 14 more
```

Comment: please add the code snippet you are using and where are you running this code. on a dataproc cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss the [spark-bigquery-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector) in your classpath, you can add it by adding the following parameter:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster "$MY_CLUSTER" --jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar ...
```